# How can I add a custom wordpress widget to show in my admin dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

I have written the code for my wordpress widget using

```
class BeginnerLinks_Widget extends WP_Widget {
```

And all that, basically doing it the 'proper' way. I added

```
function register_BeginnerLinks_Widget() {
register_widget( 'BeginnerLinks_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_BeginnerLinks_Widget' );
```

At the end of my php file which is beginnerLinksWidget.php and that is located in my wp-includes folder. But I also placed it in other areas of my htdocs as well.

Having this widget as a stand alone file did not work for me and I could not see it in my dashboard under appearance/widgets. To make it work I added the file in a plugin folder I made before, and added the widget file as a require_once() and then I was able to see it in my dashboard and use it.

Is this the only way to have a widget added to the dashboard? Is there a way to have a standalone widget without the need of a plugin.

Comment: is your requirement is to create widget ?

Comment: @rajatsaurastri not a 'requirement' but an independent widget is what i wish to implement

Comment: there are lots of tutorial available to create widget in wordpress you can follow this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/